# Using select count to verify values between 2 tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, count

Please i want a select count statement to retrieve value from a table row and verify it against another table row using php.
meaning

Hello Guys/Gurus
Please I have an issue, am some months into php and i need your help/assistance.
This is the flow. a client register at another site, when we confirm the registration, we send them a code.
The code is generated and saved in another table name called code and column generated_code.

I develop a form (http://cash2money2020.com/form.html)
So all i want is if someone inputs the generated code we sent to them, and filled it in the form, it makes a database checks to see if the code exists in the other table, if yes, submit form..if not, error message that the code is invalid and the form will not be submitted:

```
   $query   = "INSERT INTO registration 
              (id, fname, lname, address1, address2, city, state, country, email, phone, home_phone, dob, gender, living, qualification, mental, mental_details, criminal, criminal_details, kin_name, kin_phone, kin_relationship, tv_appearance, work_financial, tv_station, why, interesting, impressive,  generated_code, submitted_date) 
              VALUES 
              ('', '$fname', '$lname', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$state', '$country', '$email', '$phone', '$home_phone', '$dob', '$gender', '$living', '$qualification', '$mental', '$mental_detail', '$criminal', '$criminal_details', '$kin_name', '$kin_phone', '$kin_relationship', '$tv_appearance', '$work_financial', '$tv_station', '$why', '$interesting', '$impressive', '$code', now()) ";
```

This is what i have done so far

```
$result = mysqli_query("select count(generated) from code ");

if (!$result) echo mysqli_error();

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

$query = "INSERT INTO registration (generated_code) VALUES ('$code')";

if ($query != $row) {
      //code to submit and process the form
}
else
{
      //error message
}
```

Please help am stucked !!!

Comment: from my point of view, even this kind of pseudocode does not reflect the above requirements. Don't you need to check whether the given code is the one you have generated first before doing any insert on the database? And why do you compare an insert statement string against the code? That is always false as long as the user doesn't type that insert as "code" ... ?

Comment: Thanks @AxelAmthor, exactly what i need. to check whether the given code is the one generated, if valid, submit to d database..so what can be done?? any help will be gladly appreciated !

Comment: Q: is there a code for each user or just "some" code which only needs to exist?

Comment: no code for each user..just a random code we will send to the user and they input it in the form.

I wouldn't mind using ajax/jquery as well !!!
Please help me with the code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should do (according to the last comment):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("my_host", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$result = mysqli_query($link, "select * from code where generated = '$code'");

if (!$result) die("mysql error: " . mysqli_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);


if ( $row !== false ) {
      // code to submit and process the form
      // you might use the result with $row[<fieldname>]
}
else
{
      // error message
}
```

You need to add some error handling and unescaping values (like `$code`)

Comment: wow, amazing writeup @Axel Amthor...will definately try that out ASAP...Thanks !!!

Comment: I dont have up to 15 reputation @Axel  Amthor..how can i increase my reputation?? i deem it fit to give you an up vote..sincerely speaking ! :)